# make a div middle of parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep `#chat-inner` div in the middle of the `#chat-main` div, well I can do that by using percentage values but my problem is that there should be `2px` gap (with respect to both width and height) which a percentage value cant provide. For clear understanding please see the comment in CSS code.

**[`JSbin`](http://jsbin.com/ofipey/2/edit)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat-outline">
  <div id="chat-main">
    <div id="chat-inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chat-outline
{background-color:grey;width:30%;height:40%;
 position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;
 padding:2px;}

#chat-main
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:silver;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#chat-inner
{
  width:95%;
  height:97%;

  /*How can I give pixels here? I need 2px value*/
  margin:2.5% 2.5% 2.5% 2.5%;  

  /*margin:2px;*/

  background-color:cornflowerblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ofipey/10/edit)):

```
#chat-outline
{ background-color:grey;width:30%;height:40%;
  position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;
padding:2px;}

#chat-main
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
  background-color:silver;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

#chat-inner
{  
  top:2px;
  bottom:2px;
  right:2px;
  left:2px;  
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Would the `#chat-inner` div will be inside the `#chat-outline` div even after giving different positions? because I need to hide the chat by clicking on a button or something else.

Comment: #chat-inner will go to any place #chat-outline will go.

Comment: @Mr_Green HI why are u define position it's not requried i think Shailender Arora's answer is very clear

Comment: @RohitAzad sorry, actually I should have mentioned that I dont want to use box-sizing property. I am trying to create a cross browser compatible.(including IE). If I am wrong please correct me :)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your desired results through `padding` also :-

```
#chat-outline
{background-color:grey;width:30%;height:40%;
  position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;
padding:2px;}

#chat-main
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:silver;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:2px;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#chat-inner
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:cornflowerblue;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/UlfIBbdW)**